# Is the legacy oms_agent addon required for ama container insights for AKS?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

This documentation page describes the addon 'oms_agent' for AKS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/kubernetes-monitoring-enable?tabs=terraform#enable-container-insights

However, it only deploys the ama deployment (ama-logs-rs), which seems to use the new Azure Monitor Agent (AMA), and not the depricated Log Analytics Agent (OMS).

What is the relation between the oms_agent addon and ama?
Will the oms_agent addon also be retired once Log Analytics agent is depricated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oms_agent addon is not required anymore for Azure Monitor Agent (AMA) container insights for AKS. The documentation page you linked to only deploys the AMA deployment (ama-logs-rs), which uses the new Azure Monitor Agent. The oms_agent addon is related to the deprecated Log Analytics Agent (OMS), and it will also be retired once the Log Analytics agent is deprecated.

For AKS, if you're setting up container insights on a new cluster (specifically using the latest versions example 1.27 or 29) or migrating from the legacy OMS agent, you should use the Azure Monitor Agent.
[image]

The legacy OMS agent is only needed if you have specific dependencies on it or are running workloads that have not yet been tested or certified to work with the AMA.

Plus, you don't have to go through all this hassle, you can simply enable container insight via portal while setting up the cluster.

[image]

or through CLI

```
az aks enable-addons -a monitoring -n <cluster-name> -g <cluster-resource-group-name> --workspace-resource-id "/subscriptions/my-subscription/resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/my-workspace"
```

[image]

References:

- [Azure Monitor Agent overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agents-overview#azure-monitor-agent-overview)
- [Azure Monitor features for Kubernetes monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-overview#agent)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The documentation link however mentions that for both a new cluster and an existing cluster, if you want to enable container insights you will have to use this snippet of Terraform code:
"oms_agent {
    log_analytics_workspace_id = var.workspace_resource_id
    msi_auth_for_monitoring_enabled = true
  }"

Which seems to indicate the oms agent addon is still required?

Comment: No Roelof, not mandatory. I tried with [OMS](https://i.imgur.com/pvffjiy.png) as well as without OMS. It works without OMS block as well and picks up the latest AMA one as OMS is deprecated now.

Comment: So that means that microsoft docs are incorrect? In any case, thanks for the updates

Comment: MS doc maybe not updated yet, I tried to go as low as 1.26. that's what aks is offering the lowest aks version and went all the way upto 1.29 to validate your doubt. Seems like AMA is the new way to go.